# Ayuda con FileReader

Tags: java

Tengo una consulta que está pasando algo raro en mi código, pongo el código y prosigo a explicar

```
public void leerPuntuaciones(){     
        try {
            String puntuacion1 = "";
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("nivel 1.csv"));
            String linea = bf.readLine();
            while((linea=bf.readLine())!=null){
                //System.out.println(linea);

                String partes[] = linea.split(",");
                puntuacion1 = partes[0] +" "+ partes[1];
            }

            puntuaciones1.add(puntuacion1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Ahora, en ese archivo que estoy leyendo, sólo me reconoce la última línea y lo que quiero hacer en ese `puntuación1` es ir agregando cada una de las líneas,

¿ Tengo que añadir el `bf.readline`en un `for` o algo así?

Comment: Cuantas líneas tiene tu archivo?

Comment: Tiene más de una línea, pero a ese ArrayList (puntuaciones1) sólo me pone la última

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es lógico lees todas las líneas pero el `add` a la lista lo haces al terminar de leer ,Por eso solo añade la última ya que al salir del `while` el valor de `puntuacion1` será la ultima línea leída.

Para solucionar solo debes mover el `add` dentro del `while{...}` para que se añada a la lista cada línea leída por `readLine`

```
while((linea=bf.readLine())!=null){
      String partes[] = linea.split(",");
      puntuacion1 = partes[0] +" "+ partes[1];
      puntuaciones1.add(puntuacion1);
 }
```

Comment: Por Dios, así era, error de concentración mía, muchísimas gracias!!

Comment: y no te olvides de hacer el .close() cuando acabes tus operaciones con el fichero o usar el try con recursos para que java se encargue de ello (si usas java 1.7 o superior)

Comment: Buen punto @MaQuiNa1995.